# How to ignore files if there is an similar file with the same size?

Tags: files, file-copy

I want to list the files in a directory, using ls. Typically, the files in that directory have the same name (except for the extension - one has extension .rej, one has .failed) . 
If a pair of files with similar names have the same size, move the .failed file to a specific directory, and leave the .rej alone.

How can I do this?

Comment: You accepted my answer before it was edited. As @J.F.Sebastian pointed out, I had missed your requirement for same size files. My original answer would move any file with the same name and a `.failed` extension. Please see my updated answer for a solution that takes size into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't want to use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you want to use shell [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) and [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
$ for f in *.rej; do 
  size=$(stat --printf "%s" "${f%.rej}.failed") && 
  if [ $(stat --printf "%s" "$f") -eq "$size" ]; then
     mv "${f%.rej}.failed" backup/;
  fi;  done 2>/dev/null
```

#### Explanation

The `stat --printf "%s"` command will print the size a file in bytes. `${f%.rej}.failed` will print whatever the name of the current `.rej` file is but with the `.failed` instead of the `.rej` extension. If that file exists, then `size=$()` will exit correctly and the script will continue (`&&`). So, if the `$size` of the `.failed` file is the same as the size of the `.rej` file, then the `.failed` file will be moved to the directory `backup/`.